# Matter.Body.Rotate() causes game to not start up

Tags: javascript, html, game-physics, p5.js, matter.js

I am trying to rotate the rectangles/paddles in my matter.js and p5.js game but the game fails to run as soon as I add this line of code:

```
Body.rotate(paddle0, Math.PI/6);
```

The debugger does not report any errors but the HTML file becomes blank when I add it. The game works completely fine without this line of code and I do not know why.

Sketch.js

```
const { Engine, World, Bodies, Mouse, MouseConstraint, Constraint } = Matter;

const BOT_RADIUS = 25;
const PADDLE_WIDTH = 5;
const PADDLE_LENGTH = 25;

function setup() {
  const canvas = createCanvas(711, 400);
  engine = Engine.create();
  world = engine.world;
  startBotX = 150;
  startBotY = 300;
  bot = new Bot(startBotX, startBotY, BOT_RADIUS);
  bots = [];
  bots.push(bot);
  paddle0 = new Paddle(100,100, PADDLE_WIDTH, PADDLE_LENGTH);
  Body.rotate(paddle0, Math.PI/6);
  paddles = [];
  iterator = 0;
  for (pbot of bots){
    for(i = 0; i<16; i++){
      paddleX = BOT_RADIUS * Math.cos(i*2*Math.PI/16)+startBotX;
      paddleY = BOT_RADIUS * Math.sin(i*2*Math.PI/16)+startBotY;
      paddle = new Paddle(paddleX,paddleY, PADDLE_WIDTH, PADDLE_LENGTH)
      //Body.rotate(paddle, i*22.5)
      paddles.push(paddle);
    }
  }

  engine.world.gravity.y = 0;
  const mouse = Mouse.create(canvas.elt);
  const options = {
    mouse: mouse
  };

}

function draw() {
  background(51);
  Matter.Engine.update(engine);
  paddle0.show();
  bot.show();
  for (paddle of paddles){paddle.show()};
}
```

paddle.js

```
class Paddle {
  constructor(x, y, w, h) {
    const options = {
      restitution: 0.5
    };
    this.body = Matter.Bodies.rectangle(x, y, w, h, {options,collisionFilter: {
      mask: 0x0004
  },});
    Matter.World.add(world, this.body);
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
  }

  show() {
    const pos = this.body.position;
    const angle = this.body.angle;
    push();
    translate(pos.x, pos.y);
    rotate(angle);
    fill(255);
    rectMode(CENTER);
    rect(0,0, this.w, this.h);
    pop();
  }
```

Comment: Where did you define `Body`? You're sure there are no errors in the console? I'd expect `Body` to be part of your `Matter` destructure, or else with the full path `Matter.Body.rotate`. There are tons of global variables here. I suggest using `const` or `let` for all variable declarations to constrain scope and reduce bugs. `for (const pbot of bots){`, `for (let i = 0` and so on.

Comment: @ggorlen Body is supposed to be a module in the Matter.js physics engine which was already added in my HTML file.

Comment: Sure, but it's not in your code here. It'd be odd if you destructured it separately from the rest of the modules.

Comment: I misunderstood your question. I used Matter.Body instead of Body and it seems to work now.

Answer (score 1):

I see (at least) two problems:

1. Use `Body.rotate(paddle0.body, Math.PI/6);`. Matter.js needs to rotate a Matter.js `Body` object, not your `Paddle`.
2. `Body` was never destructured from the `Matter` object. Either destructure it or use the full path `Matter.Body.rotate`.

There were errors in the console. Usually, when the game "becomes blank" or "doesn't start", it means the program crashed before it could do anything. The best way to debug this is to look in the browser console, read the errors and fix the problems.

Beyond that, your program abuses global variables heavily. Any time you neglect using `const` or `let`, that variable becomes global, creating the possibility of subtle, confusing bugs and making it hard to understand which data is being read or written to where. Add `const` or `let` in front of all variables and scope them as tightly as possible. P5 sets you up for failure in this regard by design, but at least define everything with a `let` if you have to define it globally and initialize it in `setup`.

In other cases, there is no excuse because the variable is purely local to a loop block:

- `for (paddle of paddles)` -> `for (const paddle of paddles)`
- `for(i = 0; i<16; i++){` -> `for (let i = 0; i < 16; i++) {`
- `paddleX = BOT_RADIUS` -> `const paddleX = BOT_RADIUS`
- ...etc

I strongly suggest employing [ESLint](https://eslint.org/) and [Prettier](https://prettier.io/) to help fix your scoping and formatting issues.

Comment: I use the Node.js debugger on vscode to report errors for my javascript files. The error message it gave me was a ReferenceError saying Matter was not defined. Other than that, your fixes worked and I will definitely start using let more. But I am still confused with the ReferenceError even though the code worked and getting this message refrains me from getting useful messages while debugging.

Comment: Are you running this on Node rather than the browser? That doesn't seem likely since you're using p5. I don't think running this in Node makes sense, so if you're importing Matter in a `<script>` tag in the HTML, then running `node Sketch.js`, yeah, it's expected that `Matter` will not be defined. I'd use the browser developer tools.

Comment: I am clicking a "run and debug" button vscode allows me to do. It then prompts me to select a debug configuration (I chose node.js) and opens a debug console and debugs the file. I think this is Node but I am not entirely sure how it works. I will try using the browser developer tools instead. thanks.